# Complex Numbers trig equation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struggling with proving $|\sin(z)|\geq|\sin (x)|$ in complex numbers where $z=x+iy$.
I kinda know that I have to use trig identities and what not, but cannot find the approach. I posted a picture of where I got stuck.

Thank you[image]

Comment: What does $\;\sin x(x)\;$ mean? The product of $\;\sin x\;$ and  $\;x\;$ , i.e. $\;x\sin x\;$ ?

Comment: It was a typo I think. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\sin(x+iy) = \sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy) = \sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y).$$ Hence 
\begin{align*}
|\sin(x+iy)| & = \sqrt{(\sin(x)\cosh(y))^2+(\cos(x)\sinh(y))^2}\\
& \geqslant \sqrt{(\sin(x)\cosh(y))^2} \\
& \geqslant |\sin(x)||\cosh(y)| \\
& \geqslant |\sin(x)|,
\end{align*}
since $ |\cosh(y)| \geqslant 1$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}.$